# Convert method to and object c#

Tags: c#, object, autocomplete

I would like to convert this method into an object because I use it many times, and the only things that changes is the field "coleccion5", the one inside the foreach loop and in the return.

```
    public AutoCompleteStringCollection Auto_telefono()
    {
        DataTable dt = Datos();
        //recorrer y cargar los items para el autocompletado
        int cantidad = dt.Rows.Count;
        int contados = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            coleccion5.Add(Convert.ToString(row["telefono"]));
            contados++;
            progressBar1.Value = contados / cantidad * 30 + 70;
        }
        return coleccion5;
    }//fin metodo de llenado de autocompletado
```

Comment: *convert this method into an object*????? that's a weird question.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows the basic operation of your code now, and explain _precisely_ how you want the code to work instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `coleccion5` is the only thing changing, then pass it as parameter

```
public void Auto_telefono(AutoCompleteStringCollection coleccion)
{
    DataTable dt = Datos();
    //recorrer y cargar los items para el autocompletado
    int cantidad = dt.Rows.Count;
    int contados = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        coleccion.Add(Convert.ToString(row["telefono"]));
        contados++;
        progressBar1.Value = contados / cantidad * 30 + 70;
    }
}
```

And call it with

```
Auto_telefono(coleccion5);
```

Note also that you don't need to return the collection, since what you are passing as a parameter is a reference to the collection, not the collection object itself, because the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` class (and in fact all the classes) are [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

```
var coleccion5 = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
Auto_telefono(coleccion5);
// Now coleccion5 contains the added entries, no assignement to it needed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not a static method and add a parameter for the collection to use ?

```
public static AutoCompleteStringCollection Auto_telefono(List<T> collection)
```

where T can be added as generics on the method or 'hardcoded' if the type is always the same.